# Select statement within an Insert statement with SQLKata

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlkata

I am trying to replicate this SQL Server query in SQLKata for C#:

```
insert into ChannelData (ChannelID, DataSource, X, Y) 
values ((select ID 
         from Channels 
         where Channel = @0 and Revision = @1), @2, @3, @4)
```

I am entering `ChannelData` into the `ChannelData` table, but also storing the `ChannelID` from the `Channels` table in it. I need to retrieve the ID for the specific channel and revision number that the user has entered. How might I do this properly?

So far I have tried this, but that is the closest I got

```
query = new Query("ChannelData").AsInsert(new[] { "ChannelID, DataSource, X, Y" }, new Query("Channels").Select("ID", "@2 as DataSource", "@3 as X", "@4 as Y").Where("Channel", "=", "N01E").Where("Revision", "=", 0));
```

Is this possible to do in one SQL query, or might I have to get the ID in a different call?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();

var query =
    new Query("ChannelData")
    .AsInsert(
        new[] { "ChannelID", "DataSource", "X","Y" },
        new Query("Channels")
        .Select("ChannelID", "DataSource", "X", "Y")
        .Where("Channel","N01E")
        .Where("Revision",0)
    );


var rawSql = compiler.Compile(query).RawSql;
```

This returns:

```
INSERT INTO [ChannelData] ([ChannelID], [DataSource], [X], [Y])
SELECT [ChannelID], [DataSource], [X], [Y]
FROM [Channels] WHERE [Channel] = ? AND [Revision] = ?
```

Which, should accomplish what you want. If you're wanting to explicitly use the syntax above, you'd need to get your values first and then build your query. Keep in mind, there is a maximum number of parameters you can have (in the 1000s I think).

Comment: This has definitely got the right setup, But yeah I was using it for data entry with the @2, @3 and @4 as parameters which will be filled by my program. There isn't really a way to insert these values into the insert statement with SqlKata?